# Moving the first x characters of a filename to the end

Tags: terminal, regex, rename

I have a bunch of files or arbitrary length. I need to move the first 10 characters of the filename to the end to the end of the filename just before the extension.

If I have to use the `rename` command, how can I make rename as below,

`1234567890name.ext` to `name1234567890.ext`
`abcdefdhijklmnopqrst.ext` to `klmnopqrstabcdefghij.ext`

I'd also like to know how can I achieve the reverse, ie. take the last x number of characters before the extension and place it at the beginning of the name.

`name1234567890.ext` to `1234567890name.ext`
`klmnopqrstabcdefghij.ext` to `abcdefdhijklmnopqrst.ext`

Comment: if you're working with (any version of) windows, there's a very easy to use shareware available which can accommplish this (and much more): total commander -> www.ghisler.com  Let me know if that's a solution and if you need to know more

Comment: On Linux and based on terminal. I do have Thunar but with regex support only for search and replace function. The rename command suits the job but I don't have the regex expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rename` command uses Perl regular expression, you can do:

```
rename 's/^(.{10})(.*)(\.ext)$/$2$1$3/' 1234567890name.ext
```

**Explanation:**

```
s/                  # substitute
  ^                     # beginning of string
    (.{10})             # group 1, 10 any characters
    (.*)                # group 2, 0 or more any characters
    (\.ext)             # group 3, a dot and extention
  $                     # end of string
/                   # with
    $2                  # content of group 2
    $1                  # content of group 1
    $3                  # content of group 3
/                   # end substitute
```

The reverse command is:

```
rename 's/^(.*?)(.{10})(\.ext)$/$2$1$3/' name1234567890.ext
```

---

Updated according to comment.

If you also want to rename `name-1234567890.ext` into `1234567890-name.ext`, use:

```
rename 's/^(.*?)(-?)(.{10})(\.ext)$/$3$2$1$4/' name-1234567890.ext
```

That works as well for `name1234567890.ext`

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/Vc4ml5/1)

Comment: @flipper: You can consider [upvote the answer](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

Comment: Upvoted........

Comment: Just one more question. What if there is a hypen in between: name-1234567890.ext, how would you rename it to 1234567890-name.ext?

Comment: @flipper: See my edit.